# <button> styled with background image repeats in IE9 (browser/document modes fully IE9 and standard)

Tags: css, button, stylesheet, internet-explorer-9

I have a login page that has 2  tags that have a background image defined in HTML as:

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" name="loginButton" value="App1" class="login-button app1-logo-bkgrd align-left" />
    <button type="submit" name="loginButton" value="App2" class="login-button app2-logo-bkgrd align-right" />
</div>
```

I have the CSS classes defined as:

```
.align-left {
    float: left;
}

.align-right {
    float: right;
}

.app1-logo-bkgrd {
    background: transparent url('images/app1logo.png') top left no-repeat;
    width:220px;
    height:180px;
}

.app2-logo-bkgrd {
    background: transparent url('images/app2logo.png') top left no-repeat;
    width:220px;
    height:180px;
}

.login-button 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am using <!DOCTYPE html>

For some reason the second button (with value="App2") gets magically repeated in IE9 standards mode whereas the same HTML/CSS works fine in FF5.

If I hit the compatibility mode button it then displays correctly (IE has switched to IE7 document type - so says the dev tools).

If view source on IE 9 when the problem occurs then it shows be only one instance of the 2nd button; however using dev tools and using the selector feature it reckons there is another App2 button just after the form.

I tried removing the 1st (value="App1") button and changing the remaining button to use the same align-left class but it still gets repeated for now reason.

Anybody have any suggestions as to what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Any chance of a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually caused by a bug in IE9.

If you use a self-closing button tag which is styled with a background image then it will appear repeated in the page but only 1 of the images will be clickable. Not sure if the containing `<div>` is relevant I haven't tried without.

In my case where I had 2 buttons the 2nd button effectively fixed the bug for the 1st one which is why it was so confusing, i.e. if I swapped the order of the buttons then one that previously broken one worked.

The workaround is to use `<button></button>` syntax even though there is nothing between the open and close tag when using a background image in this way.